# CiviCRM (Drupal 7) Problem sending bulk emails

Tags: civimail, mailing

Before anything I hope you can escuse my poor english and little technical knoledge.

We are working with CiviCRM (4.2.7) on Drupal () and the function of bulk mail have sudenly stopped working.

You can prepare and redact an email and even send it, but the email is never sendt, keeping you waiting and waiting forever.

We dont have this problem sending individual mails, only with the bulk mail function.

I wonder if anyone have ever sufferd similar problems and what have they done to fix this.

Can someone help us?

Thank you all

Comment: Hi Henry, don't worry about your English or technical level, that's not what we're here for :-). That said, it looks like you forgot to include the Drupal version, but the first step would be for you to look in the scheduled job log to see if you find any errors - to do this: navigate to Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs and look for a scheduled job called something along the lines of "Send Scheduled Mailing" - click the "View Job Log" hyperlink to the right-hand side and see if it to see if there are any messages regarding job failure. Feel free to post that message here.

Answer (score 3):

Sending bulk emails depend on execution of scheduled jobs present at `civicrm/admin/job?reset=1` URL path OR `Administer -> System Settings -> Scheduled Jobs` navigation menu.

The name of the job is `Send Scheduled Mailings`. Pls check if this job is enabled and running on your site.

Also, check the status of the bulk mail you created via civimail.

[image]

- If the status is scheduled - the mailing is awaiting the execution of the scheduled job.
- If it is "Completed" - the mailing is sent to the recipients.

For more info - check https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/mass-mailings-using-civimail/

Comment: Thank you Tamar and Jitendra for your answer.

As suggested when used Send Scheduled Mailings the email is sent but we have to do it every time.

I would like to ad a new question. 

When an email is sent (in both: simple and bulk) with an attached document when this document exceeds certain size (we believe its around 900KB) the mentioned email arrives to the recipient but without the (attached) document. 

If you or someone could give us a hint of what this is happening.

As said thanks a lot.

PD: Drupal version is 7.59

Comment: The schedule job do run automatically if you've setup a cron job on your site. You can edit the job and change the frequency to match your requirements, eg run hourly, daily or every time the cron is run. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cron for more info about setting this up. Regarding the attachments - maybe, raise a separate question including some details, eg screenshot or any error you see in log files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Jitendra

From what you have pointed I am guessing that maybe we could be having a problem with the Cron 

The parameters related to bulk mailing from of our Cron are the following:

Send Scheduled Mailing

- API Prefix: civicrm_api3
- API Entity: Job
- API Action: process_mailing
- Command/Parameters: Without parameters
- Enabled?: Yes

Relative to the second question mentioned I will post a new thread as you have suggested.

Thanks